# DDEX provider 3.0.1 for Firebird with Visual Studio Pro 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, firebird, ddex

I have installed FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient v4.6.4.0 (from msi) 
and then DDEX provider 3.0.1 (from msi) to make possible data manipulation via VS.

I checked GAC in location **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\v4.0_4.6.4.0__3750abcc3150b00c** 
and there is `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll` as expected.

Unfortunately I am getting an error `"Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed"` when trying set up new data connection In Server Explorer.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64347130/ddex_problem.jpg]

I tried installation and uninstalltion providers several times, didn't helped.

Here are code from my machine.config files:
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories><add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/><add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/><add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/></DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories><add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/><add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/><add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/></DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: remove the 2nd firebird entry in the machine.config.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Thank you for hint, it was the point, however instead error with data provider, now I am getting "connection rejected by remote interface". 
I uninstalled and installed firebird 3.0 (beta2) from scratch, didn't helped.
I found some tips like copying gds32.dll from System32 directory to SysWOW64, but it didn't helped neither.

Comment: do you also get an error with FB 2.5.4? Maybe the new Authentication of 3.0 cause issues. Read here in page 42: http://web.firebirdsql.org/download/prerelease/rlsnotes/Firebird-3.0.0_Beta2-ReleaseNotes.pdf

Comment: have you tried an older firebird version?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried, it worked with Firebird 2.5. It is a pity it doesn't work with 3.0. Anyhow, thank you a lot for help! How can I mark your answer as useful (since it is a comment not answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error `"Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed"` because you have a second firebird entry in the `machine.config`. This happens due [to a bug in the installer](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-560) which is still not solved.

The `"connection rejected by remote interface"` error happens when you use Firebird 3.0, maybe because of the new authentication of 3.0. Here you have to downgrade to 2.5.4, [enable the old legacy authentication](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.firebird.dotnetprovider/8787) or wait for an update of the .Net provider to fully support Firebird 3.0 including the new authentication.

Comment: The Firebird .NET provider works with Firebird 3 when using legacy authentication, however it doesn't support the new protocol features like encryption and the new authentication. You need to change the wire encryption setting from Required (the default) to Enabled or Disabled in the firebird.conf and enable legacy authentication.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for this helpful information. Please add it as an edit to the answer because I haven't tried 3.0 jet.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel, Thank you, By disabling wire encryption I could connect!